# Windows 10 - unable to click on anything (desktop, taskbar, etc.) - but explorer.exe is not frozen

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar

This seems to happen intermittently.  I'm not longer to able to click on the taskbar or running programs like Chrome.  They respond to keyboard commands and shortcuts (windows key etc) but mouse clicks seem to be blocked by something invisible and on top of everything.

Explorer.exe is not frozen as it responds to keyboard inputs.  I'm on the latest drivers etc.

I can workaround the issue simply by hitting CTRL+ALT+DEL, then the Cancel button to get out of the menu.

After that I can click everything with the mouse normally.  I'll be good for about 30 minutes where it happens again.

I was able to capture it with OBS (using hotkey shortcuts to start recording):

https://youtu.be/U9439lVtKXc

Surely someone else out there must be experiencing the same thing.

Comment: Did you test your mouse on some other computer?

Comment: Does it happen when booting in Safe mode?

Comment: Try using `ProcExplorer64` (from the SysInternals suite), there is a feature that allows you to target any point onscreen and will identify the cursor's actuation point and bring up the running process.  It's possible there's some sort of transparent overlay being spawned to redirect your mouse clicks, in which case this would identify the malware.  You can also check if the behavior persists in safe-mode or not.

Comment: Also check event log for any errors that might happen around the time it freezes

Comment: Tried the procexp trick but didn't see anything.  I also suspected malware.  I did a Malwarebytes Premium scan as well as an in-depth scan on NOD32 but didn't find anything.

Comment: Current testing on a different mouse to see if it persists - will also try original mouse associated with the issue on another machine.